# Generate label with HTML content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, label, html-helper

Using MVC and Razor, I want to create a label for a field that contains HTML, namely a hyperlink. However, when I use the `Html.LabelFor()` method, all HTML is encoded on output.

This screenshot shows the desired result and what MVC actually outputs instead:

[image]

**Is there a way to generate a label for my model property that will correctly render HTML content?**

My ViewModel:

```
[DisplayName("I accept the <a href=\"/Terms &amp; conditions\">Terms &amp; conditions</a>")]
public bool AcceptedTermsAndConditions { get; set; }
```

My view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AcceptedTermsAndConditions)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AcceptedTermsAndConditions)
```

I also tried to directly pass the content as a "labeltext" parameter, without success:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AcceptedTermsAndConditions, "I accept the <a href=\"/Terms &amp; conditions\">Terms &amp; conditions</a>")
```

Comment: Why didn't you just use `[DisplayName("I accept the ")]` and on your view place the `<a>` tag as you normally would right after the `@Html.LabelFor`? EDIT: I'm guessing its not likely for that anchor to change the url often.

Comment: @Esteban Because that's a hack? Moving the link out of the label causes all kinds of problems, from localisation to different languages where the link might appear in the middle of the text to problems when I change the appearance of the label with CSS later. I was looking for a proper solution for the general case. There is a reason the label tag allows HTML content.

Comment: fair enough. seems like you might wanna use `@Html.Raw` for displaying your `LabelFor(m => m.AcceptedTermsAndConditions)`. have you tried it?

Comment: @Esteban: That's not going to work, the text is already encoded at that point. Yuri's answer below decodes it and then uses Raw() to prevent encoding it again, but I really dislike the unneccesary encode->decode cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own HtmlHelper method based on the decompiled sources of `Html.LabelFor()`:

```
public static IHtmlString HtmlLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string labelText = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    string str = labelText;
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    if (str == null)
    {
        string displayName = metadata.DisplayName;
        if (displayName == null)
        {
            string propertyName = metadata.PropertyName;
            str = propertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split(new[] {'.'}).Last();
        }
        else
        {
            str = displayName;
        }
    }
    string innerHtml = str;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerHtml))
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("label");
    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
    tagBuilder.InnerHtml = innerHtml;
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes), true);
    return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

The major change is that I use

```
 tagBuilder.InnerHtml = ..
```

instead of the original

```
 tagBuilder.SetInnerText(..)
```

This way the provided labelText does not end up being HTML-encoded.

Usage for my case is:

```
@Html.HtmlLabelFor(m => m.AcceptedTermsAndConditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. So instead of

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AcceptedTermsAndConditions)
```

use

```
Html.GetDisplayName(x => x.AcceptedTermsAndConditions)
```

Comment: I thought of that already, but that's not the same as LabelFor(). This way I will have to surround this manually with a label and have to set the `for="AcceptedTermsAndConditions"` attribute with a "magic string". The main advantage of LabelFor is that it takes care of the for attribute for you, setting it to the same id as the input tag.

Comment: Hoh! that was interesting

    @Html.Raw(@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
    Html.LabelFor(x=>x.AcceptedTermsAndConditions).ToString()))

Answer (score 0):

Not the cutest, but solution:

```
@Html.Raw(@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode( Html.LabelFor(x=>x.AcceptedTermsAndConditions).ToString()))
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use this:

```
[DisplayName("I accept the <a href='Terms &amp; conditions'>Terms &amp; conditions</a>")]
```

Comment: How is this different from what I was doing, apart from the change in quotes? I don't see why that would work when obviously LabelFor() encodes all HTML.